# How to enable CORS in .NET 6.0 & fix 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' error

Tags: .net, cors, .net-6.0

I have a problem running my .NET 6.0 application and I get CORS error when trying to make API requests; this is my Program.cs configuration

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000",
                                "https://example.com")
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "JWTAuthDemo v1"));
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MySiteContext>();
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:5184/api/Meal/tags. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Is there something wrong with my configuration or order, could it be something else?

I tried putting `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins)` at different places, didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

After *.AllowAnyMethod()* adding *.AllowCredentials();* solved the same problen for me.
I can also suggest changing

```
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

to

```
var CORS = "CORS";
app.UseCors(CORS);
```

Comment: Why would changing the name of the policy referenced to "CORS" help, if the policy is named "_myAllowSpecificOrigins"?